# Project convert vs2010 to vs2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to convert a VS2010 (in VB) project to VS2015 (in vb) project.

When I open the project using VS2015, I am not getting alert message asking like `this project written 2010, need to convert to 2015`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think it needs an upgrade? what happens when you now try to compile it? does it work?

Comment: when I compile it does work, just wondering why it didn't ask me? usually it asks when you open project from older version to new version.

Comment: this happened in past when you used older .net version like 2.0 in VS2005, but it looks like you used .net 4.0 which still opens fine in 2015.

Comment: Got you. Thank you sir.

Comment: is the question answered or not?

Answer (score 0):

Older Visual Studio version were bundled with a special .net version

> - Visual Studio 2002 came with .net 1.0
> - Visual Studio 2003 came with .net 1.1
> - Visual Studio 2005 came with .net 2.0
> - Visual Studio 2008 came with .net 3.5
> - Visual Studio 2010 came with .net 4.0

When you opened and old solution in a newer VS version the projects need to be upgraded to the correct .net version. Since VS2012 you can have target packs to target different .net version.

Because VS2015 still supports .net 4.0 you can compile the code fine and don't need to upgrade.

You can later change the .Net framework in project properties.

[image]